# Paragraph tags and get_page_by_title()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the `$page = get_page_by_title('$name');` to get the contest of a page to display.  However, when I use echo `$page->post_content;` the paragraphs are not *wrapped* in p tags as is usually the case when you use `the_content()` inside the wordpress loop.  Is there a way to fix this or a better method to get the content that will have the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `post_content` is the same as the unformatted input the user put in the post editor. In order to get the formatted output you have to apply the appropriate filter.

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
```

That should apply the appropriate output filter to the `post_content` field and give you the same value you would normally get from `the_content()`.